# У Су́мах чи у Сума́х?

Tags: власні-назви, наголос, іменники

Досить часто можна почути, як кажуть **у Сума́х** (з наголосом на другий склад), а не **у Су́мах**.

[Український лінгвістичний портал](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) пропонує два варіанти наголосу цього слова для усіх відмінків, окрім родового.

У той же час стаття [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8) про обласний центр зазначає тільки один наголос у називному відмінку (на перший склад) - **Су́ми**.

А коли наголос тільки один і на перший склад, то й при відмінюванні він має зберігатися, як у схожих словах [**Ду́ми**](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8), [**Ку́ми**](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8).

Якщо дійсно **Суми** з подвійним наголосом, то чим це регламентовано? Хтось зустрічав підтвердження в друкованих орфоепічних словниках?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Як свідчить [Правописний словник 1929р. (Г. Голоскевич)](https://r2u.org.ua/html/goloskevych_pered.html), для української мови природнім є збереження наголосу на першому складі:

> Су́ми, Сум, Су́мам (м.); су́мський, -ка, -ке

Обговорення наголосу у відмінкових формах назви міста Суми є на [лінгвофорумі](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=1139.25).

Щодо наголосу у місцевому вжитку цікавим є [погляд](http://sumy-blog.pp.ua/2013/11/sumskoi/) Евграфової Алли Олександрівни — кандидата філологічнихнаук, доцента Сумського державного университету, щоправда, в стосовно російської мови, але основна думка залишається прийнятною:

> «Традиционно коренные жители Сум говорят «Сумской» с ударением на
>   «о» и в «в Сумах» ударением на второй слог. Словари же всегда
>   учитывают традицию. По идее, если в словаре зафиксировано «сумской»
>   (ударение на второй слог), то и СумАх-СумАми. В этом вопросе со мной
>   солидарны и другие мои коллеги. В начале 90-х годов все коренные
>   жители без малейшего сомнения говорили «сумскОй» и в «сумАх».  Однако,
>   нужно учитывать другой момент. Исторически складывается так, что в
>   разные времена люди говорят по-разному, поэтому в одно время говорили
>   «Сумский», в другое — «Сумской». Так как норма написания нигде не была
>   зафиксирована, сегодня в литературе можно встретить обе формы
>   написания»

Але за нормативний вважатимемо варіант наголосу, вказаний в [Орфоепічному словнику](http://padaread.com/?book=84816&pg=550):

> **Суми**, Сум, у С**у**мах

А на фоні розмірковувань російськомовних лінгвістів варіант з наголосом на другому складі здається таким, що зазнав впливу російської вимови.

Comment: Наголошене `-ой` у московській мові — це велика і окрема тема. В мережі легко знайти відповідні дискусії на тему Лєв Толстой. І тому *citation needed*, бо зовсім не факт, що основна думка залишається прийнятною і для української.

Answer (score 2):

[Етимологічний словник топонімів](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Luchyk_Vasyl/Etymolohichnyi_slovnyk_toponimiv_Ukrainy.pdf) (ст. 458 пдф) також підтверджує версію Вікіпедії і дає єдиний наголос на букву "у".

А от варіант наголосу на "а", гадаю, прийшов до нас із російської мови. Бо на сайті Суми-блог, на який вже посилалася Оксана у своїй відповіді, бачимо таку інформацію:

> Исходя из всего вышеизложенного, сегодня правильно говорить «в Сума́х»
>   и Сумско́й, Сумска́я, Сумски́е.

Однак, правильним варіантом буде в "сУмах".